# Optimal pixel format for drawing on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-graphics

Pretty simple question: when doing some pretty intense drawing with CoreGraphics on the iPhone, how can I specify the pixel format to get optimal performance? Is the format that I get from the context via UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext per definition the best one? I know that RGB565 is supposed to be the fastest to use in OpenGL. Does that go for CoreGraphics as well? General advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`k32BGRAPixelFormat` and `k16LE565PixelFormat` (and their CoreGraphics equivalents) can be counted to be hardware accelerated on all iPhone/iPod touch models.